# Why is Spark breaking my stage into 3 different stages with the same description and DAG?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a 5 worker node cluster with 1 executor each and 4 cores per executor.

I have an rdd that is spread over 20 partitions that I check with the `rdd.isEmpty` method. In the spark history server, I can see three different "jobs" with the same "description":

```
JobId                         Description                           Tasks
3                             isEmpty at myFile.scala:42            1/1
4                             isEmpty at myFile.scala:42            4/4
5                             isEmpty at myFile.scala:42            15/15
```

When I click into these jobs/stages, they all have the same DAG. What might be causing the `isEmpty` stage to get broken into 3 different stages?

Additionally, when I change the RDD from 20 to 8 partitions, the History server shows:

```
JobId                         Description                           Tasks
3                             isEmpty at myFile.scala:42            1/1
4                             isEmpty at myFile.scala:42            4/4
5                             isEmpty at myFile.scala:42            3/3
```

In both cases the sum of tasks from these 3 stages equal the total number of partitions for the rdd. Why doesn't it just put in all in one stage like:

```
JobId                         Description                           Tasks
3                             isEmpty at myFile.scala:42            20/20
```

Comment: can you print the output of `rdd.toDebugString` ? That will show the execution plan for the RDD, that is, the steps it's planning to take. This will help determine what's going on. Keep in mind that only actions trigger execution (vs transfomations) but once they're triggered, you'll have stages for transformations as well (to see transformation vs action read this https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-rdd-operations.html)